# How can I tell what package requires a reboot of my system?

Tags: package-management

I have `unattended-upgrade` set up on my Ubuntu systems.   Occasionally I will log in remotely to one of them and I'll see a message informing me that I need to reboot the system (in order to complete an upgrade).   Is there a way to determine the specific package (or set of packages) which is triggering this notice?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Short version:

```
cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
```

Explanation:

Looks like there is an easy way to automatically extract the requested information.

Inside `.deb` files there are control files for installation, including `postinst` (run after installation).

For example, in `linux-image-2.6.35-25-generic_2.6.35-25.44_amd64.deb`,
 `postinst` includes

```
my $notifier          = "/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required";

my $warn_reboot     = 'Yes';     # Warn that we are installing a version of
                                 # the kernel we are running
```

and

```
# Warn of a reboot
if (-x $notifier) {
 system($notifier);
}
```

---

The shell script
`/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required` updates
 `/var/run/reboot-required` **and** `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`.

The latter file contains a list of packages requesting a reboot.

Comment: On my system the file `/var/run/reboot-required` was created a day before but there is no `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` file @ Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 26):

Reboot is recommended by the `unattended-upgrades` when it sees that a `/var/run/reboot-required` exists. The file is created by `postinst` (post-installation) scripts in some packages, it looks something like this:

```
[ -x /usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required ] && \
/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required || true
```

If you want to see which packages triggered this, you can have a look at the contents of the `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` file.

For more info also see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd).

Answer (score 4):

Based on Olli's earlier answer, I came up with a method to find all currently installed packages on your system that requires a reboot.

```
~$ mkdir debs
~$ cd debs
~/debs$ apt-get download $(dpkg -l | tail -n +7 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Wait for the download to complete, on my system it was around 900 MB so it might take a while depending on your connection. Then:

```
~/debs$ for x in $(ls); do y=$(dpkg-deb -I "$x" postinst 2>/dev/null | grep 'reboot-required'); if [ -n "$y" ]; then echo "$x" | grep -Poe '^.*?(?=_)'; fi; done
```

The output may look something like this:

```
dbus
gconf2
initscripts
libc6
libpam0g
libpam-systemd
libssl1.0.0
linux-image-3.19.0-47-generic
linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic
network-manager
upstart
```

Of course, this method is not foolproof. There might be packages that notifies about the required reboot through other means than 'notify-reboot-required', and while this shows which currently installed packages require or doesn't require a reboot, it is not certain the same will hold true for later versions of the same package.

Comment: You could acomplish the same without any tedious downloading with just `grep -l reboot-required /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst | sed -e 's,^.*/\(.*\)\.postinst,\1,'`. Note however that it will only report which packages *might* require reboot at some time, not which package *did* require reboot **this time**

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if there are other packages that require rebooting, but kernel updates always do. I'd say almost every time I've been "asked" to reboot, the kernel had been updated.

Comment: That's not good enough in my opinion. Bootloader updates also request rebooting, as well as init (upstart).

Comment: Well, also some other packages, like DBus: http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/USN-799-1 . So compiling list of packages that require restart (DBus do not always require that) is foolish for complete solution.

Comment: You're right... Mine is a partial knowledge :(. Thanks for the information. I hadn't realized other packages require restart, too.