# Why do I get a "Restart to complete updates " warning?

Tags: updates, restart

I updated my packages Ubuntu 11.10 with Update manager, and got:
"The package information was just updated" and "There are no updates to install".
But I still have the warning from the restart icon, which is highlighted red. Within it
"Restart to complete the updates" is also highlighted in red. I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` and got message as:

```
Fetched 9,465 B in 3s (2,870 B/s) Reading package lists... Done

yifang@Tan02:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is this a bug for that warning?

Comment: Basically it is the information on updates of critical things like `kernel` so that the new updates are activated after a restart. You need to restart you computer thats it.

Comment: I think Ivan is implying that nothing was upgraded during his check of system packages, but he still got the warning to restart regardless?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sagarchalise. Certain upgrades like kernel updates, driver updates and critical system and security updates need your system to restart after install. You just have to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I you didn't manually upgrade the system, then it might be that you have configured the updates to be automatically installed.

To check that:

- Open `Update Manager`
- Click on `Settings` button
- Click on `Updates` tab
- Verify the value next to `When there are security updates`
- If it's set to `Download and install automatically`, then you might want to change that to one of the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file `/var/run/reboot-required`? It is set by some packages to notify the system of the need to reboot. If not, it's probably a bug.

Also see
[How can I tell what package requires a reboot of my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system)