# Tell user to reload his pc in script

Tags: bash

I need to send a message to a user,that he needs to reload his pc, and i need to do it like some programms do (showing the red power button in the rigth top part of the screen "Reload your computer" or something like this) but i need to do it in a post installation script. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages that need to request a reboot of the system can call `/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required`, this will update a couple of files that will do what you need (setting the system indicator to red and ask the user to reboot to complete the installation).

You can look at the kernel package's packaging for more details, or this answer may also help:

[How can I tell what package requires a reboot of my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system)

Comment: it updates /var/run/reboot-required and /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs but system idicator still grey(not red at all)