# Why does apt-get not require restarts, where the update manager does?

Tags: apt, update-manager, restart

Oftentimes I try to ‘beat’ the update manager by opening a console and entering the sequence

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which, to the best of my knowledge, should update all packages to their newest stable releases. The update manager does the same, as far as I know.

However, the update manager sometimes (most frequently when a new kernel is distributed) requires a restart after terminating. `apt-get` never does, even when it looks like I’m upgrading the kernel. Why is this so?

---

In response to the duplicate vote: I am *not* asking which packages require a reboot as the linked question is. Rather I am asking *why* `apt-get` does not ask me to reboot even when I recognise a package being updated that the update manager *would* require a reboot for.

Comment: it's also worth noting that the sort of updates that are covered by `apt-get dist-upgrade` but not by `apt-get updgrade` are more likely to be those that would have caused update manager to suggest a reboot.

Comment: FWIW, you can check if restart is required by checking the existence of `/var/run/reboot-required`. Also, Byobu shows an "update required" icon in the status bar when needed.

Comment: Note that the "need to update" is not as trivial question as it may sound. For example, if upgrade fixes a glitch in a login screen (gdm/lightdm/...), do you need to restart? The example sounds funny for a server, crazy for a normal desktop, less so for a heavily shared thin station. It really boils down to *how you are using the system* which no script can really know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell what package requires a reboot of my system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system)

Comment: @Pilot6 Not even *remotely* close to being a duplicate. The question you marked is asking which packages require a reboot. My question is asking why one updating method is not asking me to reboot **even though I recognise a package being updated that would require reboots.**

Comment: OK. But it is closely related.

Comment: @Pilot6 That I can agree to ;)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Because `apt-get` (or plain simple `apt`) is for the *pros* and when the pros do a:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and see a new kernel being installed, the pros *know* they have to reboot to activate it.

*The automatic update is for everyone else out there!*

Alternatively, **you can now install [Ubuntu Live kernel Patching](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/20/live-kernel-patching-from-canonical-now-available-for-ubuntu/) from version 16.04 onwards** which allows you to update your kernel while your server is running.

**:-)**

Comment: I wish I could accept all three answers because they technically all say the same thing. But I think I’ll take yours because you made me grin most **;-)**

Comment: >:)  A little bit of humour in an answer is never bad!  ;-)

Comment: Kernel livepatching support is in mainstream kernels now, so with a bit of luck we may not have to reboot anymore once we get to LTS 16.04.

Comment: Your description of the `apt-get upgrade` vs. `apt-get dist-upgrade` matches neither `man apt-get` nor my experience using the tool. I'm pretty sure the difference has to do with how dependencies that would require installing or removing packages are handled; "upgrade" skips those packages, "dist-upgrade" attempts install/remove packages to make the upgrade happen.

Comment: @derobert: reading manual; can't find anything that contradicts what I'm saying, and it just was my experience, but that could be because of my system...  So if you have proof of the contrary, I'll remove again!

Comment: @Fabby somewhat confused as you've currently removed that paragraph, but if you look at the apt-get man page, the description of "upgrade" says e.g., "under no
           circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
           not already installed retrieved and installed.". So if a normal app update requires installing a new package (new library soname, for example), it won't be done. Or if a kernel update used the same package name, it would be done.

Comment: @Fabby the behavior you're describing is the way that turns out to work most of the time, since Ubuntu uses a new package name for each new kernel version and typically app security updates don't require installing a new package.

Comment: @Fabby unfortunately of course there can be exceptions—which will be very surprising if you understand "upgrade" to mean "not kernel" vs. "dist-upgrade" to mean "including kernel"

Answer (score 37):

Update manager suggests to restart when kernels are upgraded or some other system packages with services that are marked for reboot when upgraded.

In this case `/var/run/reboot-required` is set by a package installation script.

Command line `apt-get upgrade` does not suggest anything, because it is targeted to more advanced users that can decide themselves when to restart the system ;-)

But after upgrade using apt-get Update Manager in a while will suggest to restart too.

Comment: I can't believe that, is that true? "services that can not be restarted without rebooting the whole system."

Comment: Yes this is true. Like "upstart" and some others. Not many.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sounds ridiculous if upstart cannot be restarted without a reboot. It was supposed to be an upgrade from SysV init which can be restarted without a reboot.

Comment: @kasperd That was just an example. I noticed that Update manager asks for restart on some non-kernel packages. There must be some list of these packages. I am not quite sure upstart is there.

Comment: But will the user know after running `apt-get upgrade` whether a package that is marked for reboot has been upgraded?  It seems like something that might be useful for the user to know, regardless of whether the user is using the command line.

Comment: @MaxNanasy Update manager will popup and suggest to reboot. it may happen in a while.

Comment: @kasperd Is lack-of-reboot suddenly the only dimension on which software is judged? It's entirely possible for it to be an overall upgrade while regressing on some things.

Comment: @A.B. If you use something like [Ksplice](http://www.ksplice.com/), you don't have to reboot. Ksplice is free for Ubuntu and Fedora desktops.

Comment: FYI, packages set `/var/run/reboot-required` when the upgrade requires a reboot. See http://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd

Answer (score 15):

When you install a new kernel you have to restart the machine in order for the changes to take effect, apt-get just doesn't nag about it.

Comment: Not just kernel updates.  You also have to either reboot or restart some services when certain other packages are upgraded.  If you're savvy you can often restart relevant services and avoid a reboot.  If you're not, then a reboot will always work.  It's often not simple to work out what services need a restart, because upgraded packages could involve shared libraries that lots of other software depends on directly or indirectly via other software.  I don't necessarily 100% trust the graphical update manager to know, either.

Answer (score 7):

apt-get actually notifies you on terminal when after installing a certain package, if it requires to reboot.

update-manager is an all-in-one type of solution that takes care all of your upgrade needs by itself.

I do prefer apt-get though , don't know why :)

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get upgrade` does not update the kernel.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` updates the kernel in Ubuntu.

Linux kernel versions before 4.1 need a reboot when the kernel is updated.

Other packages don't need a reboot, just a restart of the application itself.
Some Windows applications running on Wine request a reboot but just type the command:

```
wineserver -k
```

and restart the application.