# How to update linux-image (kernel) on ubuntu

Tags: upgrade

I have following Installed package on my ubuntu: linux-image-5.3.0-1023-aws_5.3.0-1023.25~18.04.1

I want to upgrage it to package     : linux-image-5.3.0-1033-aws_5.3.0-1033.35

What is easiest way to do this ! I need to update on many machines.

I am even fine to upgrade to latest kernel. when I am trying `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ; nothing changes; `$uname -r` still returns same version.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: most of the machines are on 18.04; some are on 16.04 too :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does apt-get not require restarts, where the update manager does?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634370/why-does-apt-get-not-require-restarts-where-the-update-manager-does)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ uname -r # shows which kernel there is right now.
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo reboot # is important; otherwise till then uname -r still keep showing old kernel.
$ uname -r
```