# How can I determin if a reboot is required after update from CLI

Tags: command-line, updates, reboot

So I have an alias that I use for performing updates that cleans up old kernels and stuff. Problem is that it doesn't notify me immediately if a reboot is required afterwards. What can I use to figure this out so that I can at least print a message to the screen?

```
alias update='sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;sudo apt autoremove;'
```

Answer (score 2):

The package manager creates a file, `/var/run/reboot-required`, if the installation requires a reboot. This file is deleted when the machine is restarted.

Comment: Does it have a format or is it an empty file?

Comment: After @Muru marked it as duplicate, I searched and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system).

Comment: @Xaxon I believe it's empty, but you just need to check if it exists (e.g. with `[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]`). Also BTW, you should write a function or a script, since they're much more flexible than aliases.