# What possibley could have "automatically updated"?

Tags: updates

I powered on my Ubuntu computer and see "your computer needs to restart to finish updating."

This indicates that something automatically updated - therefore this is something that wishes my computer to act without first receiving my command.

What could be responsible for this, and how do I kill it?

Comment: How soon after you switched on? This link explains about automatic updates https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-disable-automatic-update-ubuntu Don't think it is anything sinister.

Comment: Related: [How can I tell what package requires a reboot of my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28530/how-can-i-tell-what-package-requires-a-reboot-of-my-system)

Comment: this would happen after a wakeup from suspend after updates, are you sure you didn't run updates or set updates to run automatically? I truely get the sentiment though, linux is the last bastion of machine subservience :)

Comment: I don't really remember - I was pretty sure it was after powering on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic updates in Ubuntu can be disabled in the "Software & Updates", under the "Updates" tab.

Answer (score 2):

By Default, theres several automatic Upd/Syn-Functions in the System, to ensure Actuality, Integrity and Security. These are scheduled via "Cron" and/or Event triggered.

The Restart-Request indicates a Change on the Kernel itself or its Components and Drivers.

Software-Center related Updates (Packageindex, installed Programs) can be disabled in the "Software-Updater" Settings.
The Firmware/unattended-Ups/Syns for Userspace-Config/Setup by rerouting to "/dev/null" (NOT recommended).