# What creates the file /var/run/reboot-required

Tags: reboot, packaging

Does the file `/var/run/reboot-required` ONLY occur from a kernel update, or can a developer of a software package decide herself if she wants it to be created, if desired?

The following link explain how it is created (duplicate):
[What creates the file /var/run/reboot-required](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3ukobm/what_creates_the_file_varrunrebootrequired/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#signaling-that-a-reboot-is-required) doesn't provide any guidance on when a package should use `reboot-required`, only that that's the mechanism to be used:

> ### 9.12. Signaling that a reboot is required
>
> Programs can signal that a reboot is required by `touch`ing
> `/run/reboot-required`. It is conventional to add the name of the
> package(s) requiring the reboot to `/run/reboot-required.pkgs`.
> Programs should not add a package name to `/run/reboot-required.pkgs`
> if it is already present there.
>
> The `/run/reboot-required` mechanism is used when a reboot is needed
> to fully apply the changes introduced by package installation or
> upgrade. Typically it is the `postinst` maintainer script that touches
> `/run/reboot-required`, at the end of a successful configuration of
> the package.
>
> There are no guarantees provided by the `/run/reboot-required`
> convention as to when or whether the requested reboot will occur.

So, I'd say any package maintainer can use it if they feel a reboot is required after the package is updated. Common examples include core libraries like glibc, which are used by so many things that rebooting is pretty much the only effective way to get everything to use the updated library.

One user checked the `postinst`s of a few packages and came up with varied list: https://askubuntu.com/a/731993/158442. Other examples can be found in the bug report asking for documentation on this mechanism to be included in the Debian Policy ([#919507](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=919507)).